# If statement on a mutex block

Tags: ruby, if-statement, mutex

I need to value an if condition, but I need to be careful about possible modification of a variable by other threads.

My solution is

```
array.each do |anything|
    if (mutex.synchronize do shared_var <= my_var end)
        next
    end
end
```

It seems to work. But what is exactly the `if` statement checking? And how about this other code?

```
array.each do |anything|
    mutex.synchronize do
        if shared_var <= my_var
            next
        end
    end
end
```

Are they equivalent? Does the inner `next` do its job even if it is included in a mutex? And why?

Just look at the structure, I showed only the part of the program relevant for my question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to `next` to?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, you are right, it is not clear. There is outer loop that wraps everything. I edit the question, thanks

Comment: You are aware that Array doesn't have a `foreach` method, correct?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, it is the first random loop it came on my mind, nothing about my program. I correct the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what is exactly the `if` statement checking?

[`synchronize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Mutex.html#method-i-synchronize) returns whatever the block passed to it returns, so the `if` statement is ultimately checking `shared_var <= my_var`.

> And how about this other code?

I think it's self-explanatory what the `if` statement here is checking, and it is the same as above.

> Are they equivalent?

No.

> Does the inner `next` do its job even if it is included in a mutex?

No, and this is why they are not equivalent. When `next` is called *inside* the block of the `synchronize` call, it is `next`ing in that block (not the `foreach`), which is equivalent to `return` here since there's no "next". When it's *outside* that block, it's `next`ing over the actual outer block (`foreach`) you expect.

Thus, you likely want the first code block.